# SQL call to getType() and getColumnNames() before moveToNext() failing in Android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I was wondering whether it was possible to call getType() and getColumnNames() before moveToNext().

Basically, I am trying to write the following helper functions:

```
 public static int getColumnIndex(Cursor c, String columnName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < c.getColumnNames().length; i++) {
        String realName = c.getColumnName(i);
        if (realName.substring(realName.indexOf(".") + 1).equals(columnName)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static Object getSQLValue(Cursor c, String columnName) {
    int index = getColumnIndex(c, columnName);
    if (index > -1) {
        switch (c.getType(index)) {
            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB:
                return c.getBlob(index);
            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
                return c.getFloat(index);
            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
                return c.getString(index);
            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
                return c.getInt(index);
            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL:
                return null;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

But sometimes I get an error (coming from beta testers whose database is not shared with me...) at c.getType(index), where index is 0 and size of c is 0:

```
 Caused by android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException
    Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Since **getColumnIndex** is supposed to return -1 in case of problems, how can getColumnIndex return 0 and at the same time c having no column at index 0 ?
Can it be dure to "moveToNext()" not being called prior to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you cannot get the column type unless you move to valid row and that additionally requires that the cursor itself has rows.

Therefore you need to

1. check that the Cursor actually has 1 or more rows (i.e. that it is not empty). The Cursor **`getCount()`** method, which returns an **int** can be used for this.
2. move to a valid row and for correctness move back to the row the cursor was previously positioned to.

As such I believe that the following will be what you want :-

```
public static Object getSQLValue(Cursor c, String columnName) {
    Log.d("CURSORCOUNT","Cursor has a size of " + String.valueOf(c.getCount())); //<<<<<<<<<< for demo //TODO remove me
    Object rv = null;
    int rowcount = c.getCount();
    if (rowcount < 1) {
        return rv;
    }
    int index = getColumnIndex(c, columnName);
    int pos = c.getPosition();
    boolean moveback = false;
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= rowcount) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        moveback = true;
    }
    if (index > -1) {
        switch (c.getType(index)) {
            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB:
                rv = c.getBlob(index);
                break;
            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
                rv = c.getFloat(index);
                break;
            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
                rv = c.getString(index);
                break;
            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
                rv = c.getInt(index);
                break;
        }
    }
    if(moveback) c.moveToPosition(pos);
    return rv;
}
```

- Note the above has been amended to suit the preservation of the position. If the Cursor has been moved to a row (see Cursor **c3** in testing), then that row position will be used to extract the data/type. However, if the Cursor is either before the first row or after the first row, then a move is made to the first row and the position is restored before returning.

## Testing

Assuming a db with a table and a **getRows** method that has a boolean parameter
 - if false then all rows in the table are retrieved via a Cursor
 - if true then an empty Cursor is returned

The using the following to test :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this); //<<<<<<<<<< The Database Helper
        mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase().delete(DBHelper.TBL_MYTABLE,null,null); //<<<<<<<<<< empty table
        // Add some testing data
        mDBHlpr.insert("2019-03-25T19:19:39.664Z");
        mDBHlpr.insert("\"2019-03-25T19:19:39.664Z\"");

        // Get a populated cursor (c1) and and empty cursor (c2)
        Cursor c1 = mDBHlpr.getRows(false); //<<<<<<<<<< populated
        Cursor c2 = mDBHlpr.getRows(true); //<<<<<<<<< empty
        Cursor c3 = mDBHlpr.getRows(false); //<<<<<<<<<< populated for position preservation example 
        c3.moveToPosition(1); //<<<<<<<<<< moved to 2nd row

        // Try with a non-existant column for the populated cursor
        logit(DBHelper.getSQLValue(c1,"NOTACOLUMN"),"TEST1 - NOT A COLUMN");
        // Try with a valid column for the populated cursor
        logit(DBHelper.getSQLValue(c1,DBHelper.COL_MYTABLE_MYSTRING),"TEST2 - VALID COLUMN");
        // Try with a non-existant column for the empty cursor
        logit(DBHelper.getSQLValue(c2,"NOTACOLUMN"),"TEST3 - NOT A COLUMN - EMPTY CURSOR");
        // Try with a valid column for the empty cursor
        logit(DBHelper.getSQLValue(c2,DBHelper.COL_MYTABLE_MYSTRING),"TEST4 - VALID COLUMN - EMPTY CURSOR");


        //PRESERVATION OF POSITION EXAMPLE 
        // Try with a valid column for the populated cursor
        logit(DBHelper.getSQLValue(c3,DBHelper.COL_MYTABLE_MYSTRING),"TEST2 - VALID COLUMN");
        Log.d("PRESERVED_POS", "Position is " + String.valueOf(c3.getPosition()));
    }

    private void logit(Object o,String tag) {
        String msg = "OBJECT IS NULL!!!!";
        if (o != null) {
            msg = "OBJECT IS " + o.toString();
        }
        Log.d(tag,msg);
    }
}
```

## Result

> ```
> 03-23 13:19:36.175 20570-20570/? D/CURSORCOUNT: Cursor has a size of 2
> 03-23 13:19:36.176 20570-20570/? D/TEST1 - NOT A COLUMN: OBJECT IS NULL!!!!
> 03-23 13:19:36.176 20570-20570/? D/CURSORCOUNT: Cursor has a size of 2
> 03-23 13:19:36.176 20570-20570/? D/TEST2 - VALID COLUMN: OBJECT IS 2019-03-25T19:19:39.664Z
> 03-23 13:19:36.176 20570-20570/? D/CURSORCOUNT: Cursor has a size of 0
> 03-23 13:19:36.176 20570-20570/? D/TEST3 - NOT A COLUMN - EMPTY CURSOR: OBJECT IS NULL!!!!
> 03-23 13:19:36.176 20570-20570/? D/CURSORCOUNT: Cursor has a size of 0
> 03-23 13:19:36.176 20570-20570/? D/TEST4 - VALID COLUMN - EMPTY CURSOR: OBJECT IS NULL!!!!
>
>
>
> 03-23 13:19:36.176 20570-20570/? D/CURSORCOUNT: Cursor has a size of 2
> 03-23 13:19:36.176 20570-20570/? D/TEST2 - VALID COLUMN: OBJECT IS "2019-03-25T19:19:39.664Z"
> 03-23 13:19:36.176 20570-20570/? D/PRESERVED_POS: Position is 1
> ```

### importantly, there is no exception, where there would have been an exception, and as per the last two lines, the Cursor position is preserved.

- **Note**, that every distinct combination of row/column can have it's own type and that with the exception of the rowid column or an alias thereof (*value can only be an integer for such a column*), any type of value can be stored in any type of column.
- **Note** **getInt** may not retrieve all values correctly as a column type of **INTEGER** can store 64 bit signed values, so in some instances **getLong** could be required to get valid values. Similarly, **getDouble** could be needed instead of **getFloat** to prevent loss of precision.

Comment: Thanks. I always thought that the results had always the same structure and columns, even if the columns are empty (because of complex joins). Great clarification from you :D